# How to Add Image in database using ajax in mvc?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I am new to model view controller. I have to add Fname, Mname, Lname and Image in database using ajax in an mvc application. Here's my code.

Index.cshtml

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#btnsend").click(function () {
            var name = $("#Fname").val();
            var file = $("#browseId").get(0).files;
            var data = new FormData;
            data.append("images", file[0]);
            data.append("Fname", $("#Fname").val());
            data.append("Mname", $("#Mname").val());
            data.append("Lname", $("#Lname").val());


            if (name == '') {
                alert("Fill all details!");
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Add_data",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (da) {
                        alert("Record Successfully Inserted!");
                    },
                    error: function (suc) {
                        alert("Not inserted!");
                    }



                });
            }






        })



    })



</script>
```

register.cs

```
public class register
{

    public string Fname{get;set;}


    public string Mname { get; set; }


    public string Lname { get; set; }


    public string images { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileWrapper ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public void Add_data(register rs)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("p1", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", rs.Fname);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", rs.Mname);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", rs.Lname);
            if (rs.ImageFile != null && rs.ImageFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                string filename = Path.GetFileName(rs.ImageFile.FileName);
                string imagepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImgFile/Images"), filename);
                rs.ImageFile.SaveAs(imagepath);
            }
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", "~/User-images/" + rs.ImageFile.FileName);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }



}
```

}

This is database queries

```
create table empdata
```

(
   studId int not null primary key identity(1,1),
   Fname nvarchar(50) not null,
   Mname nvarchar(50) not null,
   Lname nvarchar(50) not null,
   images nvarchar(max) not null
   )

create procedure p1
   @Fname nvarchar(50),
   @Mname nvarchar(50),
   @Lname nvarchar(50),
   @images nvarchar(max)

as
   begin
   insert into empdata values(@Fname,@Mname,@Lname,@images)

end

I want that when user click on save button all the details and image were save to database.thanks in advance!

Comment: So what specifically is not working? You've posted up front end, back end and database code. You'll have better luck if you chop out 3/4 of this post and only write what is necessary.

Comment: Image File is not inserted by using  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", "~/User-images/" + rs.ImageFile.FileName);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();  thsese lines code.